# Datasnap REST Server increasing memory usage: How to free memory of ServerMethods results?

Tags: rest, memory-leaks, delphi-xe, datasnap

In Delphi XE10 Datasnap REST project is used a TFDJSONDataSets to transfer datasets to client side.

Lifecycle: Server

The problem is: the server memory usage increases for each call, and I'm not finding a solution to free memory of datasets results.

Example:

Server Side:

```
function TServerMethods1.GetSomeDataSet: TFDJSONDataSets;  
var mt: TFDMemTable;
begin
  mt:= TFDMemTable.Create(nil); 
  result:= TFDJSONDataSets.Create;
  //load mt data...
  TFDJSONDataSetsWriter.ListAdd(result, mt);
end;
```

Client Side

```
function TClientModule1.GetSomeDataSet: TFDMemTable;
var ds: TFDJSONDataSets;
begin
  result:= TFDMemTable.Create(nil);  
  ds:= ServerMethodsClient.GetSomeDataSet();
  result.AppendData(TFDJSONDataSetsReader.GetListValue(ds, 0));
  result.Open;
end;
```

Every call to TServerMethods1.GetSomeDataSet increases the memory usage of App Server. What's the correct way to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please release the used MemoryTable.

```
function TServerMethods1.GetSomeDataSet: TFDJSONDataSets;  
var mt: TFDMemTable;
begin
  mt:= TFDMemTable.Create(nil); 
  try
    result:= TFDJSONDataSets.Create;
    //load mt data...
    TFDJSONDataSetsWriter.ListAdd(result, mt);
  finally
    mt.free
  end;
end;
```